# How to get current country name in blogger or blogspot.com

Tags: javascript, jquery, blogger, blogspot, blogger-dynamic-views

In blogger or blogspot we can add html or javascript tag from layout  then add gadget. How to enable a div on the basis of different countries?

Comment: You can utilize GeoIP services like http://ip-api.com/docs/api:json , https://geojs.io to get the country of your visitor and accordingly show/hide gadgets on the page based on that information

Comment: @PrayagVerma i have found some APIs and tried but could not find a way to use it in blogger. Can you suggest a way to use the API you recommended in blogspot?

Answer (score 0):

to get current country name in blogger use this code

```
<b:eval expr='data:blog.locale.country'/>

<script>

 var country = <b:eval expr='data:blog.locale.country'/>;
console.log(country);

</script>
```

(Abdo)

Answer (score 0):

By default, make all the `div`'s hidden. Sample code using one of the GeoIP services would look like -

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
  function geoip(json) {
    window.onload = displayInCountry(json);
  }
  function displayInCountry(json) { 
    if (json.country === 'Austria') {
      document.querySelector('#DIV-ID').style.display = "block";
    }
 }
//]]>
</script>
<script type="application/javascript" src="https://get.geojs.io/v1/ip/geo.js"></script>
```

You will need to replace the `#DIV-ID` with the ID of your Div element.